# Decoding a SAMLResponse in JSP from query string

Tags: java, xml, jsp, saml

I have a simple JSP page to show a decoded SAML Response that has to be received as query string. Here's the code:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/xml" %>
<%@ page language="java" import="java.io.*" %>
<%@ page language="java" import="java.util.*" %>
<%@ page language="java" import="java.util.zip.*" %>
<%@ page language="java" import="javax.xml.parsers.*" %>
<%@ page language="java" import="org.w3c.dom.*" %>
<%@ page language="java" import="org.xml.sax.*" %>
<%@ page language="java" import="javax.xml.transform.*" %>
<%@ page language="java" import="javax.xml.transform.dom.*" %>
<%@ page language="java" import="javax.xml.transform.stream.*" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

<%!
    private static Document convertStringToXMLDocument(String xmlString) {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder;
        try {
            builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();          
            Document doc = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlString)));
            return doc;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
%>

<%
    String responseMessage = (String) request.getParameter("SAMLResponse");
    responseMessage = responseMessage.replaceAll("\\s", "").trim();
    byte[] base64DecodedResponse = Base64.getMimeDecoder().decode(responseMessage);
    String outputString = new String(base64DecodedResponse);
    Document doc = convertStringToXMLDocument(outputString);
    Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
    transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "4");
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
    Source source = new DOMSource(doc);
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    Result res = new StreamResult(writer);
    transformer.transform(source, res);
    String SAMLString = writer.toString();
%>

<c:set var="SAMLResponse" value='<%= SAMLString %>' />

<c:out value='${SAMLResponse}' escapeXml="false" />
```

The problem is that when the received SAML is really long the page doesn't seem to work anymore and i'm not able to correctly decode it. I want to point out that if i create something like:

```
String responseMessage = "<long encoded SAML here>";
```

and i proceed with the computation the JSP page shows what is expected. Is this somehow related to the query string being cut by the browser or received in a format that is not String?
Thanks

Comment: I'm not going to answer the "how do I fix this". Instead, I'm going to point out some security issues with what you've done thus far. Putting the Response in a query parameter is putting that authentication token in everything that has access to the URL. This is bad security, and most commercial systems will not support Responses sent as a query parameter. The other thing that I would say is that nowhere in your code are you doing signature validation of the response and this is a massive issue.

Comment: Hi, first of all this won't be production code, it is just a test for an homework. Second, `request.getParameter("SAMLResponse")` is also used to retrieve POST data, so not a big of a deal. Do you have any ideas on how to solve the problem or you just wanted to give some security tips?

Comment: Does it happen on every browser? Just one? Since you say your code can work with a a form POST, does that succeed when the query parameter doesn't? Do you have any code for debugging, like echoing the query parameter received to ensure you got the whole thing or if the browser cut it off? Is there any error being thrown in the browser's debugger?

Comment: It happens on any browser, and i saw that the SAML comes with some spaces in it, and that's why i used the `replaceAll()` method to remove them. The browser debugger returns a generic 400 error.

Comment: Forgot to say: same behavior even with POST method, but i get this error when trying to decode: Input byte array has wrong 4-byte ending unit

Comment: Something sent in a query parameter should be URL encoded, while Form would not be. Do you have sample data that you are using that you can post?

Comment: I'm using a well known IdP to test my code and it returns sensitive data so i cannot share it. I am now using a sample SAML Signed Response from samltool.com and i pasted it here: [link](https://pastebin.com/XnTHxSxV) 
With this example, i get the error:  `Content is not allowed in prolog`